# Mapping a Series with a NumPy array -- dimensionality issue?

Tags: numpy, pandas

When I'm using 2d array maps, everything works fine. When I start using 1d arrray's this error occurs; `IndexError:  unsupported iterator index`. This is the error I'm talking about:

```
In [426]: y = Series( [0,1,0,1] )
In [427]: arr1 = np.array( [10,20] )
In [428]: arr2 = np.array( [[10,20],[30,40]] )
In [429]: arr2[ y, y ]
Out[429]: array([10, 40, 10, 40])
In [430]: arr1[ y ]

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-430-25b98edce1f3> in <module>()
----> 1 arr1[ y ]

IndexError: unsupported iterator index
```

I'm using the latest Anaconda distribution with NumPy 1.8.1. Maybe this is related to a NumPy bug [discussed here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/6168)?
Could anybody tell me what is causing this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to either convert the Series to a array, or vice-versa. Indexers must be 1-d for a 1-d object.

```
In [11]: arr1[y.values]
Out[11]: array([10, 20, 10, 20])

In [12]: Series(arr1)[y]
Out[12]: 
0    10
1    20
0    10
1    20
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect.  Looks like I need to work on my understanding of numpy indexing.

Comment: if need be you can convert a 2-d to a 1-d with ``arr.ravel()``

Comment: Good to know.  I was also working around with arr2[y,0] but wanted to figure out what was happening in case I was not understanding how numpy works (which I obv wasn't!)